# Как посчитать сколько раз вызывалась функция, не выходя за её рамки? Python

Tags: python, функции

Всем доброго вечера. Есть такой код:

```
import math

n = 999

def cycle(a):
    b = math.prod(list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(a))))
    return b if len(str(b)) == 1 else cycle(b)

print(cycle(n))
```

Он разбивает двузначное (и больше) число на отдельные числа. И перемножает их пока результат не будет равен одному числу. Например, при n = **999** он выдаст **2**. А внутри всё будет выглядеть так:

```
1) 9*9*9 = 729, 2) 7*2*9 = 126, 3) 1*2*6 = 12, 4) 1*2 = 2
```

То есть потребовалось **4** действия, чтобы получить результат с **одним** символом. Вопрос - как в самой функции вернуть это количество действий? Не выходя за её рамки. То есть кроме *n = ...* за пределами функции ничего быть не должно

А итоговый результат должен быть такой:

```
n = 999
def cycle(a):
   .....
print(cycle(n))
>>>> 4
```

Или

```
n = 7
def cycle(a):
  .....
print(cycle(n))
>>>> 0
```

Comment: А что обозначает `cycle(b) and cycle(b)`?

Comment: ой, это ошибка была. Удалил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import math

n = 999


def cycle(a, step=1):
    b = math.prod(list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(a))))
    return (b, step) if len(str(b)) == 1 else cycle(b, step + 1)


print(cycle(n))
```

```
(2, 4) # первое число в кортеже - результат, второе - кол-во шагов
```

Answer (score 3):

Чем проще, тем лучше. Рекурсия:

```
import math


def cycle(n):
    if n < 10:
        return 0
    return cycle(math.prod(map(int, str(n)))) + 1


print(cycle(int(input())))
```

> ```
> $ echo 999 | python cycle.py
> 4
>
> $ echo 729 | python cycle.py
> 3
>
> $ echo 126 | python cycle.py
> 2
>
> $ echo 12 | python cycle.py
> 1
>
> $ echo 2 | python cycle.py
> 0
> ```

Comment: Красиииво. Но вообще не понимаю как это работает) Понятно что делает map и т.д. А как обратно цикл запускается не могу понять

Comment: Она спускается на самое дно, ничего не делая. После того как дно достигнуто, функция считает сколько произошло возвратов. Возвратов столько же, сколько было вызовов. Каждый вызов - один шаг в цепочке преобразований.

Comment: [SICP](https://web.archive.org/web/20180717041720/https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). Там сложно и непонятно. А потом сразу просто и понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, вариантов масса:

****C использованием декоратора****

```
import math

n = 999

def counted(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.calls += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.calls = 0
    return wrapped

@counted
def cycle(a):
    b = math.prod(list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(a))))
    return cycle.calls if len(str(b)) == 1 else cycle(b)

print(cycle(n)) # 4
```

**С использованием глобальной переменной**

```
import math

n = 999
global counter

def cycle(a):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    b = math.prod(list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(a))))
    return counter if len(str(b)) == 1 else cycle(b)

counter = 0
print(cycle(n)) # 4
```

**С использованием переменной у функции**

```
import math

n = 999

def cycle(a):
    cycle.counter += 1
    b = math.prod(list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(a))))
    return cycle.counter if len(str(b)) == 1 else cycle(b)

cycle.counter = 0
print(cycle(n)) # 4
```

Выбирайте какой нравится.